# Can Python's logging module be limited by number of lines instead of size in bytes?

Tags: python, logging

Can Python's [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module be limited based on a number of lines, instead of size in bytes?

I have a real-time application with several components, and I would like to monitor each component's output in a different terminal so I thought of using `logging` to redirect each component's output to its own file. I could then do `tail -f component1.log` on one terminal, `tail -f component2.log` on another, and so on.

However, if I run the system for a long duration of time, then the logs' size would blow up and take too much space. So ideally, the logs would clear themselves after a certain number of lines (e.g. restart after 1000 lines).

The [`RotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) is the closest, but this opens different files, so I would have to stop `tail` on the first log, then run it once more on the second log, and so on.

Would the best way, in this case, be to just write a custom handler that does the above?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is not achievable.  Even you are just truncating the file (instead of rename + creating new one with same name), the file handle opened by `tail` is going to be invalidated (e.g. `tail -f ` will show you error like `tail: foo.txt: file truncated`)

Comment: Instead, when you are doing `tail`, you could do `tail -F name FileName` which it will retry when the opened file is gone.  Such behavior will work with `RotatingFileHanlder` anyway